# Откуда WordPress цепляет статичный код в конце каждой страницы, кроме футера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

Доброго дня! Такой вопрос по WordPress. Если открыть страницу в режиме просмотра исходного кода, то в конце страницы есть вот такой участок кода:

```
<!— fancybox —> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://centr-schastja.ru/wp-         content/plugins/wppage/js.." media="all"/> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://centr-schastja.ru/wp- content/plugins/wppage/js.."></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 jQuery(function ($) { 
 $('.ps_make_order').fancybox({ 
 'padding': '20', 
 'autoScale': false, 
 'type': 'inline', 
 'href': '#order_popup' 
}); 
 $('a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".gif"]').fancybox(); 
}); 
</script> 
<!— //fancybox —>
```

Там же далее он цепляет jquery и wppage. Мне нужно в этом тексте кое-что изменить, где ВП цепляет этот код?

Comment: Почему кроме футера. Скорее всего там и цепляет. Выводится функцией `wp_footer()`

Comment: Хорошо, а где увидеть и отредактировать wp_footer()?

Comment: Эта функция выводит контент, генерируемый через хуки (action) `wp_footer`. В частности, скрипты регистрируемые `wp_enqueue_script()`, В вашей теме (и, возможно, в плагинах) нужно искать хуки `add_action('wp_footer', ...)`;

Comment: Кстати возможны другие варианты, но в одном вопросе всего не охватить. Нужно смотреть всю тему

Comment: ищи в папке с плагином wppage

Answer (score 0):

можно проще, берешь например нот пад ++ или тотал командер, или что нибудь похожие и ищещь внутри файлов необходимый тебе кусок кода(например искать в файлах `<!— fancybox —>`). как правило результатом будет один два файла, дальше уже легче будет разобраться.